# Why programs on stm32 can only be debugged to run?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, armclang

I use armclang build my program，and the progarm will let LED on in board.But when I downlaod program to stm32f407 by st-link, the LED is not on.So I run the program in debug mode by st-link, zhe LED will ON,it mean that the program is running.

I found that the program can run in O3 optimization, and can't run in O2 optimization.

why?

I use armcc build the program,everything is ok.So is the problem with armclang or am I overlooking some configuration.

Please enlighten me, thank you

Comment: You have an undefined  behaviour bug.

Comment: Without any code and build scripts we can't figure out the problem

Comment: Occam's razor suggests that you should first blame your own newly minted code used by only you before blaming the tools used by thousands of professional developers in real-world applications every day for years!  So to help, we need to see the code, because it is not armclang - rather you have probably developed code with undefined behavior - such behavior may change between compilers and with different compiler options. If you have a debugger, debug it - see exactly what is happening.  Normally you'd debug with `-g -O0` (at which your code may well work as it happens).

Answer (score 0):

To run the program in the board without debug mode, you should reset the board with the black button.